# How to load URL in Ionic Framweork

Tags: cordova, url, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a very simple android app for that I am using ionic framework for that I am using default template with left menu and each link has a template url . But here I want to load the url of my site for each link suppose when I click on link sport it load the my website url/sports link . Not in json whole as it is in the browser .

Comment: can you share what you have attempted?

Comment: Right now I have a default template with slide menu he on left menu I need to add a link to my current site like url/sport  and want to load whole website as it is is it possible simple webview

Comment: You mean if someone click on any menu tab, it should open your site?

Comment: yes but inside the app

Comment: I know a solution but that will cover your whole app then,I mean only that page will take place of whole frame, until you go back.Will that work?

Comment: no problem so I will hide all default template and will show only url of my site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88182/discussion-between-mudasser-ajaz-and-nilay-singh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [inappBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) for this purpose.It will open any external url in your application and has different `target` options.